# Filling a hole in a face with loop cuts forming a 2-way intersection?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have a mesh that forms a plane with loop cuts running in both directions. Part of this area is cut out and I need to fill it back up, maintaining the loop cuts in both directions. Is there an automated way of doing this? If not, what's the easiest method?

[image: Screenshot of mesh]

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I don't think this is really a duplicate of that, this question is asking how to do it specifically while maintaining the loop cuts across the filled area.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That was weird geometry in that question. This is specifically a grid fill (now that I know its name). I have nominated their for reopening.

Comment: @Keavon I'm marking it as a duplicate because its basically asking the same thing and the other question has more info.

Comment: @iKlsR Ah, yes, this is a duplicate of that. Previously it was marked as a duplicate of a different question which it was not a duplicate of, but the one it's now a duplicate of is similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the number of vertices are matching on opposite sides you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>> *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Also found in *Mesh> Faces> Grid Fill* from the header menu in the 3D view.

Comment: Wow! Useful trick! I don't know why but it works properly for me only if I select the two opposite edges (like with 'Bridge Edge Loops' tool) and then press CTRL+F-->Grid Fill. When I select the whole edge loop it merges the edges in a strange way.

Comment: As long as the number of opposite edges are equal it should work. If it doesn't you can play around with the 'offset' option.

Comment: @Gonzou Try playing with the *offset* option in the F6 menu.